# NLog Database Error Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: nlog, .net-7.0

Trying to get NLog logging to the database. Running IIS with .net 7. Have the following packages included in my project
[Image of Project Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8hcZ.png)

Getting the following error:
Error DatabaseTarget(Name=MessageStoredProcedure): Failed to create ConnectionType from DBProvider=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

My nlog looks like this

```
<target name="asyncReqResMessage" type="AsyncWrapper">
    <target type="Database" name="MessageStoredProcedure">
        <keepConnection>true</keepConnection>
        <dbProvider>Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,Microsoft.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
        <connectionString>Data Source=****.company.org,1433; Initial Catalog=Logging; User ID=*****; Password=****; Connection Timeout=30; Application Name=test;</connectionString>
        <commandText>EXEC logInsertExternalRequest @EndPoint, @Method, @LogKey, @Server, @TokenId, @ReceivedDate, @RequestType, @RequestIP, @RequestHeaders, @RequestMessage, @ResponseDate, @ResponseHeaders, @ResponseMessage, @ResponseCode, @ResponseId, @Duration</commandText>
        <parameter name="@EndPoint" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=EndPoint}" />
        <parameter name="@Method" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=Method}" />
        <parameter name="@LogKey" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=LogKey}" />
        <parameter name="@Server" layout="${machinename}" />
        <parameter name="@TokenId" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=TokenId}" />
        <parameter name="@ReceivedDate" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=ReceivedDate}" />
        <parameter name="@RequestIP" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=RequestIP}" />
        <parameter name="@RequestType" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=RequestType}" />
        <parameter name="@RequestHeaders" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=RequestHeaders}" />
        <parameter name="@RequestMessage" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=RequestMessage}" />
        <parameter name="@ResponseDate" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=ResponseDate}" />
        <parameter name="@ResponseHeaders" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=ResponseHeaders}" />
        <parameter name="@ResponseMessage" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=ResponseMessage}" />
        <parameter name="@ResponseCode" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=ResponseCode}" />
        <parameter name="@ResponseId" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=ResponseId}" />
        <parameter name="@Duration" layout="${event-properties:logInfo:objectpath=Duration}" />
    </target>
</target>
```

Made sure the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll is in the bin directory.
Made sure I updated the dbprovder to the following: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks